# entity framework 6 dbinterception

Tags: entity-framework

I've just upgraded our solution to 6.0.1 of the Entity Framework and set up a class that implements IDbCommandInterceptor.

My question is, why would I see Insert commands going through the ReaderExecuting/ Executed handlers rather than the NonQueryExecuting/ Executeded handlers?

In another scenario I retrieve an object from the database, update a member of one of its associated collections and then savechanges and this Update command does go through the NonQuery handlers.

I've gone to get a clone of Entity Framework from Codeplex to try figure out why it decides to call into the ReaderExecuting/ed handlers, but no joy as yet.

The application is calling other Select commands during the time of the insert that could confuse matters?

Any pointers much appreciated.